# Flutter and firebase cloud messaging, send a notification with an API?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

With Flutter and cloud messaging, is it possible to send a push notification to one or more devices (with tokens) not with the Firebase console, but with a web API, PHP, NodeJS ... ?

Comment: we can use rest api to send the fcm notification https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-fcm-rest-api-7719925f2e3e

Answer (score 1):

What you want is possible, but not in the way you're thinking. The best way to handle this is to have your flutter app contact your backend through an API and then the backend would send the notifications to the devices using firebase cloud messaging.

Comment: True, It works, but I'm trying to do it through a web API

Comment: Maybe give some more details so I can better understand where you're stuck at :)

Comment: I don't want use the Firebase Console but an API to send notifications

Answer (score 0):

Check out Firebase Admin SDK or their simple JS Web api.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple

Comment: Ty, no I want use a REST API